# startIndex cannot be larger than length of string in c#

Tags: c#

I tried to test the month of the staff working whether equal 3 months from they started work till now. And this is what I am trying to use :

```
int totalMonth = 3;
int totalYear = 0;
int mon = DateTime.Now.Month;
int yr = DateTime.Now.Year;
//block of code that I used LinQ to Entity to get staff start work date
result = result.Where(((s => mon - int.Parse(s.StartDate.Substring(3, 2).ToString()) == totalMonth && yr -int.Parse(s.StartDate.Substring(6, 4).ToString()) == totalYear))).ToList();
```

The format of date in my database is `07/05/2012` But I got the error :

```
startIndex cannot be larger than length of string. Parameter name: startIndex
```

Could any one tell me , what did I wrong here? Thanks in advanced.

Comment: Your code works on a variable named result. But we can't see neither the type or its current value. Could you elaborate on this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> The format of date in my database is 07/05/2012

Most likely the date is stored as binary and has no format. And what you see when listing the records could be different from what happens in C#.

Use the debugger to find out what `result.First().StartDate` actually looks like. Could be `"5-7-12"`.

Comment: But the data type is `varchar(50)` not `date`.

Comment: And do you allow NULL dates? Because for at least one record there are less than 6 chars.

Comment: @socheata that's your root problem.  You should store dates as dates, not strings.